# What are graphics being displayed at the end of the section?

Tags: graphics, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I am including graphics into my latex documents as below:

```
\begin{figure}[abc]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{abc.eps}
\end{center}
\caption{Same caption}
\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

Only the first image is being displayed where I have inserted it. Rest all images are being displayed at the end of the section.

Note: I have designed some images in Dia diagram editor and converted them to PNG. Then I used `convert abc.png eps3:abc.eps` to convert them to EPS format.

Comment: This is normal. The `figure` environment is a float and is supposed to float through the text until some suitable place is found. See [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned). Also `[abc]` is a invalid optional argument of `figure`. And don't use the `center` environment, but the `\centering` macro.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a floating environment you shouldn't use an environment like `center`. You get additional vertical space. It is better to use `\centering`

```
\begin{figure}[abc]
\centering
%\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{abc.eps}
%\end{center}
\caption{Same caption}
\label{fig:abc}
\end{figure}
```

The optional argument of a floating environment like `figure` is the positioning,

```
h=here
t=top
b=bottom
p=extra page
```

You use `abc` which makes no sence. I prefer:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
```

Some more explanation you can find here:
[Wikibook LaTeX/Floats, Figures and Captions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions)